# How many times does a brower request for an image or any media from the server

Tags: html, rendering

I think the title covers pretty much everything. how many times does a browser request for a file eg an image whick is used in several places on the same page? I have the same image being used severally and I would like to know how how to help client minimize bandwidth usage if the browser is gonna request it many times

Comment: one time only. that why we do CSS sprites http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

The browser will download the image once and then cache it. So if it requests the same image again it will display the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same image(same path) it will download only one time, unless you set the image to no-cache.